# Flow not covered

Tags: react-native, flowtype, exponent, expo

Get warning "Not covered by Flow"(3 warnings on one line)

on line:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Use Flow.js v.0.48.0.
Code sample:

```
...
import { Font, AppLoading } from 'expo';
...
export default class App extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
     this.loadFonts();
  }

  async loadFonts () {
    await Font.loadAsync(fontsStore);    
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it looks like Flow is unable to find types for the `expo` module. It looks like they are not currently available on [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed), but you are welcome to submit them. You can also just create [library definitions](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/) for your own use. Basically you will need to describe the external interface of the `expo` package. Flow will then use the types you provide to type check your code that uses the `expo` package.